# npm command is not found when ssh with bitbucket pipelines on shared hosting

Tags: node.js, ssh, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I've installed nodejs as described [here](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/installable-applications/manual-installations/installing-node-js-on-managed-hosting-accounts).

Everything works fine when I ssh to the server myself. But I've created a script that deploys my application and call it via bitbucket pipelines. Everything else works fine (`composer install`, `php artisan migrate` etc.), except `npm install`. The error message is

> ./deploy: line 26: npm: command not found

In bitbucket-pipelines.yml I call my script like this:

```
- step:
    script:
      - ssh user@ip_address ./deploy
```

When I call the script by myself everything works. The problem is only with bitbucket pipelines. I have no clue why this happens :(.

Comment: Is `./deploy` your own custom script? Also, what command do you run when you do `ssh` to the remote machine manually?

Comment: Yes, deploy is my custom script. It pulls new changes from bitbucket, installs new frontend and backend dependencies and things like these. I just run ./deploy, when I connect manually.

Comment: Ok. I am curious to know what exact command you use to _connect_ to that machine and not the command you run _after_ connecting to that machine.

Comment: I use Putty. I also tried in command line with the same command I use in pipelines. It works.

Comment: See, such issues of binary not found (`npm` in your case) happens when you are running a command with a user who is different from the one with which the binary was installed. To make it clearer, the user used in `ssh` command in your `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` i.e., `ssh user@ip_address ./deploy` should be the _same_ as the one you use to connect when you use PuTTY.

Comment: It's the same but I will try something that you reminded me of.

Comment: Try configuring the path to `npm` in that user's `~/.bashrc` file

Comment: It's interesting because composer is working. Both commands are added to ~/bin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198445/discussion-between-technext-and-nikolay-traykov).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running `which composer` revealed that at least `composer` command is not getting picked up from your *assumed* location i.e., `~/composer` dir. Instead, it was found in `/opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer`.

`which npm` returned the following:

```
no npm in (/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin:/usr/local/jdk/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/root/bin:/opt/bin:/opt/cpanel/composer/bin:/home/handmast/.local/bin:/home/handmast/bin)
```

Now since you are able to manually run the command `npm`, you just need to figure about the path from where `npm` is running and ensure that the path is *explicitly* added to the user's `~/.bashrc` file and things should work fine. You need to do this because as per your observation, `ssh` is not able to find it.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/npm/binary
```

Note: To avoid any confusion, just remember that while adding the path to your binary, you just have to add the path to the directory where `npm` resides. Don't add `npm` at the end. For example, following is *incorrect* way:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/handmast/bin/npm
```

Correct way is this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/handmast/bin
```